# Rust PyO3 linking with cc failed

Tags: rust

I am compiling a pyo3 example code using cargo build. I see this error at the end

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Other codes compile fine. I see this error only when I use pyo3.

I am using MacBook with M1 chip. I have Xcode installed.
Rust toolchain stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
Python 3.82 (arm64)

This is how I am seeing my dependencies for pyo3

```
[dependencies.pyo3]
version = "0.14.5"
features = ["extension-module"]
```

What worked for me

1. changing python to x86_64 and rust toolchain to x86_64. This works.

Does anyone else have issues compiling rust with arm Mac?

This is the example code that I am trying https://github.com/bedroombuilds/python2rust/tree/main/15_pymod_in_rust/rust/pyo3_monte_carlo_pi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve it by adding this to cargo.toml file

```
[target.x86_64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-undefined",
  "-C", "link-arg=dynamic_lookup",
]

[target.aarch64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-undefined",
  "-C", "link-arg=dynamic_lookup",
]
```

Obtained from the [PyO3 docs](https://pyo3.rs/v0.20.2/building_and_distribution#macos)